# Adding leading zeros to a column in csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv file with 3 columns of data. I want to format the third column by adding leading zeros to it and write it to a new file.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 1 | 33 |
| 8 | 1 | 82 |
| 6 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 | 481 |

I want it to look like this instead:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 1 | 0033 |
| 8 | 1 | 0082 |
| 6 | 1 | 0005 |
| 3 | 1 | 0481 |

I am fairly new to coding so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a pure *Python* approach, I would use [`writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) & [`zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) this way :

```
import csv

with open("file.csv", "r") as in_file:
    reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    header = next(reader)
    rows = [[r[0], r[1], r[2].zfill(4)] for r in reader]

with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

With [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), you can try this :

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

(pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=",").assign(C=lambda x: x["C"].astype(str).str.zfill(4))
    .to_csv("output.csv", index=False, sep=",")) # <- adjust the new sep/delimiter here
```

Output (*output.csv*) :

```
A,B,C
9,1,0033
8,1,0082
6,1,0005
3,1,0481
```

Comment: I approached it the same way but I keep getting a list index out of range for some reason. Do you know how I would fix that?

Comment: Can you add your code to the question ? Also, can you make your csv *as plain text* and not in a tabular format ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very naïve method, but I hope this helps. Let's start from basics

```
data = {
 "a":[9,8,6,3],
 "b":[1,1,1,1],
 "c":[33,82,5,481]
}
#load data into a DataFrame object:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

To loop through elements of a column you can use this:

```
for x in df.c:
    print(x)  #33,82,5,481
```

Now if you want to add fixed number of zeroes to the column, you can do:
1.Create an empty list
2.Append list with all column values with leading zeroes.
3.Update value of column with the list

```
n = [] 
for x in df.c:
  n.append("00"+str(x))#append list with all column values with leading zeroes
print(n)  #['0033', '0082', '005', '00481']
df.c = n   #Update value of column with the list
```

A shorted method would be to use list comprehension

```
n = ["00"+str(x) for x in df.c]
print(n)  #['0033', '0082', '005', '00481']
df.c = n
```

But since in your question I saw that the last column has only 4 digits, I used this small logic to get results accordingly

```
n = []
for x in df.c:
    if len(str(x))==0:
        n.append("0000"+str(x))
    elif len(str(x))==1:
        n.append("000"+str(x))
    elif len(str(x))==2:
        n.append("00"+str(x))
    elif len(str(x))==3:
        n.append("0"+str(x))
    else :
        n.append(str(x))

print(n)  #['0033', '0082', '0005', '0481']

df.c = n
print(df)

#   a   b   c
#0  9   1   0033
#1  8   1   0082
#2  6   1   0005
#3  3   1   0481
```

To save it into a file you can use

```
df.to_csv("new_data.csv")
```

Hope this helps you!